# is it possible to communicate with a Service by calling it's methods?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

as mentioned [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#servicecommunication) and as all developers do, there are several ways for an `Activity` to communicate with a `Service`. the most popular ways are using Intent data and binding. is it possible to communicate with a service simply by calling it's methods ? **if it is possible, is it a good way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to return service instance from the binder. Take a look [at this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for an example of how to do this.

Extracted from the article linked above (look for the line: `int num = mService.getRandomNumber();`).

*LocalService.java*

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return 5;
    }
}
```

*BindingActivity.java*

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;

            // Call the method from service
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @Soheil - yes, it's completely reasonable. You just have to remember that any method you call on this service will be called in the same thread as your activity. So if you need this service to do the long-running job, use `AsyncTask`, threads or something similar.